# Removed WooCommerce image- full screen width

Tags: image, woocommerce, product

I'm using WooCommerce and I would like to remove the product image and instead have a full page description/addons.

Using below code, (wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php) I was able to successfully remove the image

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20
```

However, a **large white space remains** on the left. I tried adding code to wp-content/themes/themename/custom.css but it did **not** work

```
.single-product .product .summary { width: auto; }
```

How can I remove the empty/white space (where the product image normally was)?

Comment: Hi,
With the latest Woocommerce update, this no longer works. I can still see the image. Can someone advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `.single-product .product .summary` to:

```
.single-product .product .summary 
{ 
   width: 100% !important; 
   float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this did not work. Do you have any other suggestions? @Howlin

Comment: Without seeing the makeup of the page (or the page itself) no sorry.

Comment: Sorry try my edit, you will need to add `!important` to the end.

Comment: Thanks :) I also want to stop MediaGrid from resizing my thumbnails too small. I've written the shortcode in the HTML section of a Gravity form.  [Here's a link to a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028960/mediagrid-thumbnails-tiny-within-gravityform-html)